# scrapy post header has two 'Content-Length' fields

Tags: python, scrapy

when I using scrapy.http.Request to post null data to specific url, I always found the post header sent by scrapy has two 'Content-Length' fields, Here is my request code:

```
    yield Request(
        self.url,
        self.parseReport,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.header,
        meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}
    )
```

my header is:

```
    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "http://192.168.4.188:8081/Service",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
```

I kown scrapy will append the 'Content-Length' field automatically，but my header does not contain any 'Content-Length' field, and the packets captured
by wireshark indicate that post header has two those fileds， the response  give status code 400. 
[here is the post header screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQayG.png).
can anyone help，many thks.

Comment: What is your Scrapy and Twisted versions? (output of `scrapy version -v` ). It looks like an integration bug between Scrapy, which [patched missing `content-length: 0` some time ago](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1800) in Scrapy 1.1.0 , and new Twisted version which [patched the same bug](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/pull/670) in v 17.1.

Comment: FYI, I opened an issue on Scrapy's bug tracker: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2677

Comment: my crapy version is 1.3.3 and the version of Twisted is 17.1.0, it seems the problem exists stll.

Comment: Indeed, the bug has only been opened. It's not fixed. You can downgrade Twisted to v16 and it should work.

Comment: thanks paul, it truely works when I downgrade the twisted to v16.6.0.

Comment: downgrading to v16.6.0 didn't work for me